# Change value in array of dictionary swift 5

Tags: swift

**I am using xcode 10.2 and swift 5**

I need to change all values from "**selected**" key = false/true in "**arrNotificationList**"

```
    // Create mutable array
    var arrNotificationList = NSMutableArray()

    // viewDidLoad method code
    arrNotificationList.addObjects(from: [
        ["title":"Select All", "selected":true],
        ["title":"Match Reminder", "selected":false],
        ["title":"Wickets", "selected":false],
        ["title":"Half-Centure", "selected":false],
        ])
```

**I have try with below code but original array "arrNotificationList" value not changed.**

```
        arrNotificationList.forEach { value in
            print("\(value)")
            var dictNotification:[String:Any] = value as! [String : Any]
            dictNotification["selected"] = sender.isOn // this is switch value which is selected by user on/off state
        }
```

Comment: Why are you using dictionaries in the first place? Looks like you only have a fixed set of keys (`title`, `selected`). Looks like a struct would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change elements of an array use [`map`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3017522-map) function instead of [`forEach`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1689783-foreach). Then return change changed dictionary in map function

```
var arrNotificationList = [[String:Any]]()

arrNotificationList = [["title":"Select All", "selected":true],
                        ["title":"Match Reminder", "selected":false],
                        ["title":"Wickets", "selected":false],
                        ["title":"Half-Centure", "selected":false]]
arrNotificationList = arrNotificationList.map({
    var dict = $0
    dict["selected"] = sender.isOn
    return dict
})
print(arrNotificationList)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, instead of using `NSMutableArray`, use `Swift` array of type `[[String:Any]]`, i.e.

```
var arrNotificationList = [[String:Any]]() //array of dictionaries

arrNotificationList.append(contentsOf: [
    ["title":"Select All", "selected":true],
    ["title":"Match Reminder", "selected":false],
    ["title":"Wickets", "selected":false],
    ["title":"Half-Centure", "selected":false],
    ])
```

Now, since it is an `array of dictionary`, and `dictionary` is a value type, so any changes done to it in `foreach loop` won't reflect in the original `dictionary`.

Use **`map(_:)`** to get a new array with `selected = sender.isOn` for all the `dictionaries` in `arrNotificationList` array.

```
        arrNotificationList = arrNotificationList.map {
            ["title": $0["title"], "selected": sender.isOn]
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but when I try to code with arrNotificationList.map then error will appear "Use of unresolved identifier 'val'"

Comment: It will fail if any of the dictionaries has more than 2 values. ex: `["title":"Match Reminder", "selected":false, "subtitle":"remainder"]`

Comment: @arunsiva There can be different solutions for futuristic requirements.